# load SDK inside SDK in production in Android

Tags: android, sdk, packaging

Looking for solution to load SDK inside my SDK in production. I have a SDK which is getting integrated in many Android Applications with in my org.

I need to have a packaging structure where App A needs certain features of my SDK & App B needs certain features of my SDK via other SDKs inside my SDK.

I can not enable everything in my SDK as increase in size will affect size of different apps which do not require every feature.

Comment: Have you tried adding full sdk with R8's `minifyEnabled true`? It should automatically delete unused code

Comment: @SergeiKozelko, Code is usable but it will be decided in production. It won't work for me.